# Who can delete a branch in VSTS?

Tags: azure-devops

I am the owner of the Visual Studio Team Services account. I created a repo, it has 2 branches. I have given access to everyone i.e. every member can access the repo.

[image]

Though my team member didn't create the branch, he wanted to delete it, but he couldn't and I could(I also didn't create the branch). When I checked we have the same level of access i.e. both project administrators.

What could be the reason behind this issue?

Answer (score 32, accepted):

If you are both Project Administrators, you should check if the user has been set permission separately.

In **Version control** Tab `https://account.visualstudio.com/project/_admin/_versioncontrol?`, check if the user has been set permission separately:

- Check in the repo level: select the repo (such as Git2 in below example) -> check if the user has been set permission separately -> if yes -> check if Force Push as Deny -> if yes -> Clear explicit permissions.

  [image]
- Check in your two branches separately: select each branch -> check if the user has been set permission separately -> if yes -> check if Force Push as Deny -> if yes -> Clear explicit permissions.

  [image]

Comment: I did this but still see Delete Branch option

Comment: The option will be always visible, but if you click it denies the execution!

Answer (score 3):

Check **Force push (rewrite history, delete branches and tags)** permission for repo under Settings > Version Control is set to **Allow**. Force push to a branch, which can rewrite history and this permission is also required to delete a branch.

Comment: I did this but still see Delete Branch option

Answer (score 1):

Check your user access by going to /_settings/repositories, then add a user and review your Access control summary.

I was part of a group with an explicit "Deny" which overrode other groups.

It should look something like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It seems, for those using Azure DevOps 2019, that you need the `"Bypass policies when pushing"` permission as well.  At least it was needed today.